# Pipenv: Won't Install

Tags: windows-10, pipenv

I am trying to learn Django and I am following a websites instructions to install pipenv. I am using the Windows PowerShell, and every time I try to use a pipenv command such as pipenv shell or anything else, it says "The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path was included, verify that the path of correct and try again." I have pip and pipenv both installed and the file path of pipenv is C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages. I cannot figure out how to make things work. I might be glancing over some things, but I tried uninstalling python, reinstalling, make sure the PATH is included, and nothing I can do seems to work. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt, type "pip install pipenv".

That should be the end of it.

Comment: When I type that in, it says "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable." Then it lists off 10 messages saying "Requirement already satisfied: ".